# What is the Pro or Cons for mosaic 30 GB jp2000?

Tags: arcmap, erdas-imagine, envi, mosaic

Has anyone tried mosaic jp2000 imagery in ERDAS, ArcGIS , ENVI or any softwares that they have accomplished ?

I have three jp2000 files that is total about 28.1 GB that I want to mosaic with ?

Comment: Should be no trouble for ERDAS so if you have is just try. Can't say anything about ArcGIS and ENVI. GDAL is good too if it has a good JPEG2000 driver.

Comment: Ok. I can give that a try.

Comment: The trouble with mosaicing JP2K is the not-quite-nodata created by a lossy compression will overwrite adjacent images (unless the compression is lossless). I would definitely go with ERDAS as you can define your 'data area' for a smooth seamline and it is considerably faster than Esri at raster processing operations. GDAL is fast too but lacks the tools by default for a masked mosaic operation - if you're considering GDAL then perhaps the QGIS interface (and some plugins) would be the way to go. Yes, I have done this in GDAL but images were all data to the edge.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson - Good to hear..Yeah what I am the most concern is that once you mosaic these jp2 files it has to uncompressed first and then mosaic and then compressed again and save as a jp2000 again ? Do I make myself clearly ?

Comment: Yes, that's the way I did it. I used GDALbuildvrt to make a single image but compressing direct from VRT with JP2K tiles to single JP2K was *very* slow and crashed. The way I did it was VRT with JP2K tiles -> Uncompressed GeoTiff -> JP2K. The uncompressed image was over 5 TB (I had to do it on Adaptec RAID as no single disc was big enough).. you could try LZW/Deflate compressed GeoTiff but it's still going to be *very* big. If you have access to ERDAS try that first, it has its own drivers which may not have the same problems going compressed to compressed image.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson  Here I have ERDAS 2013 and ENVI 5.0.

Comment: I have neither, but have used ERDAS in previous employment, hence the need to try to do this in GDAL (or Esri). I also have MicroImages TNTmips which is good with images but uses its own internal format which means it would still need to be exported; the TNT JP2K driver wasn't suitable for this task so I ended up doing it all in GDAL (it took over 1 week to process on an I7 3.7GHz with Adaptec 6805 RAID).

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson  That is another concern about nowdays the computer has a hard time catching up very large imagery datasets..Ever remember the movie "WarGames" They had the server....That is what we need to make the geoprocessing run faster and smoother...

Comment: I remember that movie - I saw it on betamax. That was a Cray Mainframe with 1024 processors @ 3.14MHz - that's only 3.2 GHz combined. The rate determiner for this is HDD access which is still rotary storage in the capacity that's required. GIS Raster has always pushed the limits of storage, I can remember trying to fit a 10GB BIL file on a 20GB drive! What we need is something like Google or Dreamworks server farm!

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson  Oh that is MainFrame I forgot about that word.